# C# register external dll callback

Tags: c#, pointers, dll, callback

I use Visual Studio Community 2015 and Visual C#.
I'm in trouble in order to have a signature Pad to work.
This Pad is connected via USB and a "dll" is provided in order to get the signatures.

I'm used to work with WinDev but I think there's a problem with callbacks...
So I decided to try with C# but since I'm a beginner I'm in trouble.

I created a project, allowed "unsafe" code, nd coded my first function which is to initialize the Pad.
It works well, since there's no complex types for this call.
It thickens with callback pointers.

Here's the documentation extract for the procedure declaration provided by the manufacturer:
--- The one which works :

```
Format: BYTE uSign300_OpenHid(UINT auiVid, UINT auiPid)
Parameter: auiVid The Vendor ID
auiPid The Product ID
Return: BYTE : 0=FAIL, 1=SUCCESS (these are constants defined earlier)
Example: uSign300_OpenHid(0x0ACD,0x1320);
```

--- The two which cause me troubles

```
Function: uSign300_AddPointHandle
Description: Register a call-back function for StartCapture function, the function will be called when receiving signature data
Format: **BYTE uSign300_AddPointHandle(PSIGN_FUNC func,LPVOID pParam)**
Parameter: func The name of call-back function
The format of PSIGN_FUNC is typedef void **(WINAPI *PSIGN_FUNC)(int*,int, LPVOID)**
The first parameter is data buffer
The second parameter is the length of data.
Please see demo code for more information.
pParam The current pointer
Return: 0=FAIL
Example: uSign300_AddPointHandle(point_handle,this);
```

And my code:

```
namespace uSign300ns
{

    public static class retcode
    {
        public const byte SUCCESS = 0x01;
        public const byte FAIL = 0x01;
        public static char sdialog;
    }

    unsafe public class uSign300
    {
        const string _dllLocation = "uSign300Kit.dll";
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_OpenHid(uint auiVid, uint auiPid);
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern bool uSign300_Close();
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_ClearSignature();
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_AddPointHandle(void* func, void* pParam);
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_StartCapture(byte f_Mode, byte f_Interval, byte s_Red, byte s_Green, byte s_Blue, byte b_Red, byte b_Green, byte b_Blue);
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_ExitCapture();
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte uSign300_ControlLED(byte leftLED, byte rightLED);

        //
        // --- Méthode d'initialisation
        public static bool __uSign_000_Connect()
        {
            bool bRet = false;
            byte nRet;
            nRet = uSign300_OpenHid(0x0ACD, 0x1320);
            if (nRet == retcode.SUCCESS)
            {
                bRet = true;
            }
            if (bRet)
            {
                // on éteint les LEDs
                uSign300_ControlLED(0x00, 0x00);
            }

            return bRet;
        }


        private void __uSign_callback(void* __ptr_data, int datalen, void* __ptr_dialog)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Callback appelée");
        }


        public static bool __uSign_100_StartThreadedCapture()
        {
            bool bRet;
            byte nRet;
            //void* __ptr_callback;
            //string sChaine;
            nRet = uSign300_ClearSignature();

            // enregistrer la callback
            fixed (char* __ptr_dialog = &retcode.sdialog) {
                uSign300_AddPointHandle(__uSign_callback, __ptr_dialog);
            }

           

            bRet = true;
            return bRet;
        }
    }
}
```

And here, the sample code in C provided by the manufacturer

```
void __stdcall point_handle (int *buf, int rev, LPVOID pParam)
{   

    for(int i = 0; i < rev;)
    {
            int point_x;
            int point_y;
            point_x = buf[i++];
            point_y = buf[i++]; 
    }
}

void OnStartcapturing() 
{
    uSign300_AddPointHandle(point_handle,this); 
    AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc_Capture, this);
}
```

I'm not able to have the compilation working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least one mistake, but I can't assure that's the root of the problem.

To pass a callback function pass a delegate, not a void*:

```
delegate void PSIGN_FUNC(int* buf, int rev, void* pParam);
```

Then you declare the dll call as this:

```
[DllImport(_dllLocation)]
public static extern byte uSign300_AddPointHandle(PSIGN_FUNC func, void* pParam);
```